# Xcode - toolbar or views not showing near top

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I got a new MacBook and I downloaded a newer copy of Xcode. Newer than what I was previously using on my old Mac. I copied over my app from an older version Mac and Xcode. Now, all the screens are acting weird. The toolbars have round corners and won't show at the top. They also can be dragged down and dismissed. That's not what I want. If I create a new screen with a toolbar it is at the top until I add a segue.

I will add some screenshots to demonstrate the issue.

What could be causing this and what can I do to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

iOS 13 introduces a new design of **modalPresentationStyle** for modally presented view controllers. and that's why you see tool bars have round corners and won't show at the top.
if you want to see your view controller stick to top of your screen just add this before you presenting any view controller

```
yourViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the visual way to remove what you're talking about -- Go to the segue connected to the ViewController with the issues and edit it so it is Full Screen.